# Extracting raster data outside of clip

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, masking

I'm trying to extract Sea Surface Temp raster (floating integer) that includes both sea temp and land surface temp.  I want the data outside of a clip.  I've clipped the coastline with a polygon in Arc 10.2, however, the issue is with the remaining desired data outside of a polygon.  I've tried extract by mask without success as it will only return values within the polygon and not outside of it.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Would simply using the Erase tool in the Analysis toolbox suffice?

Answer (score 3):

- Make a big polygon around your entire study area, on and offshore
- Use the [Symmetrical Difference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000r000000) tool to get the difference between your coastline polygon and your study area polygon to create an *offshore* polygon
- Extract your raster data using the *offshore* polygon

Comment: @JenniG fantastic!!!